# cannot boot windows 10 after fixing ubuntu boot problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 15.04

I installed ubuntu 15.04 alongside windows 10 but ubuntu could not boot so i fixed it with boot repair but now windows cant boot as well. 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12715713/

Answer (score 1):

First **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot** (if present) in your **Windows 10 installation**.
Boot into Windows, open **command prompt as administrator** and execute command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

**Shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Then reinstall the GRUB bootloader to your Ubuntu installation.

Boot from the Ubuntu install media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda5` = system partition ... (taken from your pastebin output).

Now you should be able to select the operating system to boot from GRUB boot menu.